# Incorrect syntax near 'PROVIDER' on LocalDb

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, localdb

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name], [type] 
    FROM [sys].[database_principals] 
    WHERE [type] = N'E' AND [name] = N'userId')
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [userId] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
    ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [userId]
    ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [userId]
END
```

Running this against an Azure SQL DB works.

LocalDb fails with `Incorrect syntax near 'PROVIDER'`.

**I understand why.** Is there a workaround for LocalDb?

Comment: Check the EngineEdition server property value and add conditional processing

Comment: The syntax will not parse is the real issue. I could check the type, but the TSQL is still there, invalid to LocalDb.

Comment: The version and edition of your engine affect the syntax rules - plain and simple. There is no switch that will ignore bits of tsql code that apply only to certain platforms. You either write tsql that is platform independent or you write dynamic tsql (or compartmentalize it) to use or adjust the syntax based on the platform.

Comment: Are you running this from a dacpac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the document [CREATE USER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments):

`EXTERNAL PROVIDER` is only Applies to: SQL Database, SQL Data Warehouse.
[image]

A new syntax extension, **FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER** is available for creating server-level Azure AD logins in SQL Database managed instance.

This means local/on-premise SQL Server doesn't support this syntax.

I searched and didn't find any workaround about AAD for local/on-premise SQL server.

We still could using bellow syntax to make is look likes `Azure_Active_Directory_principal` :

```
USE master
CREATE login [leon@****.com] with password='****'

USE Mydatabase
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name], [type] 
    FROM [sys].[database_principals] 
    WHERE [type] = N'E' AND [name] = N'userId')
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [leon@****.com] FOR LOGIN [leon@****.com]
    ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [leon@****.com]
    ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [leon@****.com]
END
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you use sqlcmd (or a .dacpac) you can use this conditional syntax:

```
if SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') > 4
begin
   :r ContainedUser.sql
end
```

For performance reasons, I recommend that you do not create a login, but just a contained user:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name]
                FROM [sys].[database_principals]
                WHERE [name] = N'DbUser')
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [DbUser]
    WITH PASSWORD = '$(DbUserPassword)';

    GRANT CONNECT TO [DbUser];

    ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [DbUser];
END
```